# change PHP to generate dynamic SQL

Tags: postgis, openlayers, sql, php

I'm catching features from my PostGIS database with PHP, which generates dynamic sql requests. Since I can't manage to wrap my response into an `ol.layer.Image` I thought about using `ST_UNION` or `ST_COLLECT` to improve map rendering performance. My current generated SQL is looking like this:

```
SELECT krs,class, st_asgeojson(st_transform(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(the_geom,0),4326),6) AS geojson 
FROM tbl_detailansicht_f 
WHERE krs = 'Rotenburg (Wümme)'  AND class = 5 AND the_geom &&  st_transform(st_makeenvelope(7.981262207031247,52.23004870271677,11.112365722656248,53.695628373000176,4326),4326)
```

I would like to get a sql statement like this:

```
SELECT krs,class, st_asgeojson(st_transform(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(st_collect(the_geom),0),4326),6) AS geojson 
FROM tbl_detailansicht_f 
WHERE krs = 'Rotenburg (Wümme)'  AND class = 5 AND the_geom &&  st_transform(st_makeenvelope(7.981262207031247,52.23004870271677,11.112365722656248,53.695628373000176,4326),4326)
GROUP BY krs, class
```

So my PHP (by https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON) needs to be adjusted in order to consider this change, which I fail at.

```
    <?php
/**
 * GET GeoJSON from PostGIS
 * Query a PostGIS table or view and return the results in GeoJSON format, suitable for use in OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc.
 * Author:  Bryan R. McBride, GISP, adapted by G.Moes
 * Contact: bryanmcbride.com
 * GitHub:  https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON
 * 
 * @param       string      $geotable       The PostGIS layer name *REQUIRED*
 * @param       string      $geomfield      The PostGIS geometry field *REQUIRED*
 * @param       string      $srid           The SRID of the returned GeoJSON *OPTIONAL (If omitted, EPSG: 2169 will be used)*
 * @param       string      $fields         Fields to be returned *OPTIONAL (If omitted, all fields will be returned)* 
 *                              NOTE- Uppercase field names should be wrapped in double quotes
 * @param       string      $parameters     SQL WHERE clause parameters *OPTIONAL*
 * @param       string      $orderby        SQL ORDER BY constraint *OPTIONAL*
 * @param       string      $sort           SQL ORDER BY sort order (ASC or DESC) *OPTIONAL*
 * @param       string      $limit          Limit number of results returned *OPTIONAL*
 * @param       integer     $precision      digits of returned geojson 6 = 0.111 m submeter as DEFAULT *OPTIONAL*
 * @param       real        $simplify       simplify geometry to >5.0m as DEFAULT *OPTIONAL*  
 * @param       string      $offset         Offset used in conjunction with limit *OPTIONAL*
 * @return      string                  resulting geojson string
 */


# Connect to PostgreSQL database You need to pass here the credentials to connect to Your database
require("./connect.php");


function escapeJsonString($value) { # list from www.json.org: (\b backspace, \f formfeed)
  $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
  $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
  $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
  return $result;
}


# Retrive URL variables
if (empty($_GET['geotable'])) {
    echo "missing required parameter: <i>geotable</i>";
    exit;
} else
    $geotable = $_GET['geotable'];
if (empty($_GET['geomfield'])) {
    $geomfield='the_geom';
} else
    $geomfield = $_GET['geomfield'];
if (empty($_GET['srid'])) {
    $srid = 4326;    // changethis if You need another standard SRID
} else
    $srid = $_GET['srid'];
if (empty($_GET['fields'])) {
    $fields = '*';
} else
    $fields = $_GET['fields'];
$parameters = $_GET['where'];
$bbox = $_GET['bbox'];
if (empty($_GET['precision'])) {
    $precision = 6;    // change this to Your needs
} else
    $precision = $_GET['precision'];
if (empty($_GET['simplify'])) {
    $simplify = 0;   // change this to Your needs
} else
    $simplify = $_GET['simplify'];    
$orderby    = $_GET['orderby'];
if (empty($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sort = 'ASC';
} else
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
$limit      = $_GET['limit'];
$offset     = $_GET['offset'];



# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a GeoJSON element in EPSG: 4326
$sql = "SELECT " . pg_escape_string($fields) . ", st_asgeojson(st_transform(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(" . pg_escape_string($geomfield) . ",".$simplify."),4326),".$precision.") AS geojson FROM " . pg_escape_string($geotable);
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) > 0) {

      $sql .= " WHERE " . str_replace("''", "'", pg_escape_string($parameters));
}
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) > 0 AND strlen(trim($bbox)) > 0){
     $sql .= " AND the_geom &&  st_transform(st_makeenvelope(".pg_escape_string ($bbox).",4326),".$srid.")";
}
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) <= 0 AND strlen(trim($bbox)) > 0) {
      $sql .= " WHERE the_geom &&  st_transform(st_makeenvelope(".pg_escape_string ($bbox).",4326),".$srid.")";
}
if (strlen(trim($orderby)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY " . pg_escape_string($orderby) . " " . $sort;
}
if (strlen(trim($limit)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT " . pg_escape_string($limit);
}
if (strlen(trim($offset)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " OFFSET " . pg_escape_string($offset);
}
//echo $sql;
# Try query or error
$rs = pg_query($db_connection, $sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n";
    echo $sql;
    exit;
}
# Build GeoJSON
$output    = '';
$rowOutput = '';
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $rowOutput = (strlen($rowOutput) > 0 ? ',' : '') . '{"type": "Feature", "geometry": ' . $row['geojson'] . ', "properties": {';
    $props = '';
    $id    = '';
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        if ($key != "geojson") {
            $props .= (strlen($props) > 0 ? ',' : '') . '"' . $key . '":"' . escapeJsonString($val) . '"';
        }
        if ($key == "id") {
            $id .= ',"id":"' . escapeJsonString($val) . '"';
        }
    }

    $rowOutput .= $props . '}';
    $rowOutput .= $id;
    $rowOutput .= '}';
    $output .= $rowOutput;
}
$output = '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ ' . $output . ' ]}';

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode( $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it!

```
  $sql = "SELECT " . pg_escape_string($fields) . ", st_asgeojson(st_transform(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(ST_Collect(" . pg_escape_string($geomfield) .   "),".$simplify."),4326),".$precision.") AS geojson FROM " . pg_escape_string($geotable);
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) > 0) {

      $sql .= " WHERE " . str_replace("''", "'", pg_escape_string($parameters));
}
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) > 0 AND strlen(trim($bbox)) > 0){
     $sql .= " AND the_geom &&  st_transform(st_makeenvelope(".pg_escape_string ($bbox).",4326),".$srid.")";
}
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) <= 0 AND strlen(trim($bbox)) > 0) {
      $sql .= " WHERE the_geom &&  st_transform(st_makeenvelope(".pg_escape_string ($bbox).",4326),".$srid.")";
}
if (strlen(trim($orderby)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY " . pg_escape_string($orderby) . " " . $sort;
}
if (strlen(trim($limit)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT " . pg_escape_string($limit);
}
if (strlen(trim($offset)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " OFFSET " . pg_escape_string($offset);
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY " . pg_escape_string($fields);
```

sadly that doesn't improve map rendering performance at all.